# how to prevent adding of namespaces to child nodes of root when namespaces are required only in root

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I had problem in adding the namespace to root.. somewhat root required was like this:

```
<railml version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://www.railml.org/schemas/2009"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.railml.org/schemas/2009 http://www.railml.org/schemas/2009/railML-2.0/railML.xsd">
```

I tried to solve myself like

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.railml.org/schemas/2009";
var doc = new XDocument();
XElement root = new XElement(xmlns+"railml");
doc.Add(root);
XAttribute ver = new XAttribute("version", "2.0");
root.Add(ver);
XNamespace ds = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace schemaLocation = "http://www.railml.org/schemas/2009 http://www.railml.org/schemas/2009/railML-2.0/railML.xsd";
XAttribute x2 = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dc", ds.NamespaceName);
XAttribute x3 = new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName);
XAttribute x4 = new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation.NamespaceName);
root.Add(x2);
root.Add(x3);
root.Add(x4);
```

the namespaces are adding but problem coming is that while adding xmlns it is adding this namespace to all the childs of root **
how to fix this..
**I have multiple tags in this xml and those tags have multiple child tags and their children having multipl childs too..
I found a solution to add namespaces to child also but then namspace adds to their sub child too..
Is there any way to remove or prevent this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about recursion?

```
private static XElement AddNamespace(XElement element, XNamespace ns)
{
    return
        new XElement(
            ns + element.Name.LocalName,
            element.Attributes(),
            element.Elements().Select(x => AddNamespace(x, ns)));
}
```

Adds a namespace to and element and all descendant elements. Applying it to `XDocument.Root` can give you the entire new document with namespace added to all elements.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

    var ns = "http://my-namespace.com";
    var newDoc = new XDocument(AddNamespace(xDoc.Root, ns));
}
```

Comment: this works fine but one problem i faced was some xml(s) have metatag/metadata which have namespaces other than xmlns or ns(as in my ques and your answer) like dc and xsi as in my code in question  it removes those other namespace too. so i solved it by adding metadata to newDoc.Root at the end,then save newdoc